# MySQL - SELECT column from all tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

how can i select a column from all selected tables ? like (throws an error):

```
SELECT *.id FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
```

i wouldnt do it like this, because there are a lot of tables, and they will change:

```
SELECT table1.id, table2.id, table3.id, table4.id FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
```

only the id, so this isnt useful as well:

```
SELECT * FROM table1, table2, table3, table4
```

is there a nice solution ?

greets

Comment: generate the query programatically!

Comment: simple way is: `SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t4.id FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3, table4 t4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `UNION`, like this:

```
SELECT id FROM table1
UNION
SELECT id FROM table2
UNION
SELECT id FROM table3
UNION
SELECT id FROM table4
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Alias Names like Table and prefix that alias name with the column name

Example : TableName  aliasname

then use select t1.columnname from Table1 t1

```
  SELECT t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t4.id FROM table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3, table4 t4
```

Comment: Could you add some additional info, along with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The very nice solution,less error prone and flexible is writing down all the columns you want to fetch in the same order you want it to be:

```
SELECT 
   t1.id as t1_id, 
   t2.id as t2_id, 
   t3.id as t3_id, 
   t4.id as t4_id 
FROM 
   table1 t1, table2 t2, table3 t3, table4 t4
;
```

do you want to do CROSS JOIN?

**Advantage:**
you have diff name/reference for each column